# Calculate statistics of one numpy array based on the values in a second numpy array

Tags: numpy, statistics, numpy-ndarray

Lets say I have a 2-d numpy array

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
              [1, 1, 2, 2],
              [3, 3, 4, 4],
              [3, 3, 4, 4]]
```

and a 3-d numpy array like

```
b = np.array([[[1, 2, 8, 8],
               [3, 4, 8, 8],
               [8, 7, 0, 1],
               [6, 5, 3, 2]],
              [[1, 1, 1, 3],
               [1, 1, 4, 2],
               [0, 3, 2, 1],
               [3, 2, 3, 9]]])
```

I want to calculate the statistics (`mean`, `median`, `majority`, `sum`, `count`,...) of `b` according to the "IDs" in `a`.

Example: `sum` should result in another array (or a list if that is easier), that gives the `sum` of the values in `b`. There are 4 unique "IDs" in `a`: `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, and 2 'layers' in `b`. For the 1's in `a` that is a sum of 10 (layer 0) and 4 (layer 1). For the 2's 
 it's 32 (layer 0) and 10 (layer 1), and so on...

Expected result for `sum`:

```
sums = [[1, 10,  4],
        [2, 32, 10],
        [3, 26,  8],
        [4,  6, 15]]
```

Expected result for `mean`:

```
avgs = [[1, 2.5, 1.0 ],
        [2, 8.0, 2.5 ],
        [3, 6.5, 2.0 ],
        [4, 1.5, 3.75]]
```

My guess, is that there is a handy function in numpy that does that already, but I am not sure what to search for exactly. Any pointers of how to do it, or what to search for, are much appreciated.

**Update:**

I came up with this for-loop, which is fine for very small arrays. However, my arrays are much larger than 4 by 4 and a faster impementation is needed.

```
result = []
ids = np.unique(a)
for id in ids:
    line = [id]
    for band in range(0, b.shape[0]):
        cell = b[band][np.where(a == id)]
        line.append(cell.mean())
        # line.append(cell.min())
        # line.append(cell.max())
        # line.append(cell.std())
        line.append(cell.sum())
        line.append(np.median(cell))
    result.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
cal_sums = [[b[j, :, :][np.argwhere(a==i)[:,0],np.argwhere(a==i)[:,1]].sum() 
             for i in np.unique(a)] for j in range(2)]
cal_mean = [[b[j, :, :][np.argwhere(a==i)[:,0],np.argwhere(a==i)[:,1]].mean() 
             for i in np.unique(a)] for j in range(2)]

sums  = np.zeros((np.unique(a).size, b.shape[0]+1))
means = np.zeros((np.unique(a).size, b.shape[0]+1))

sums[:, 0] , sums[:,1:] = np.unique(a), np.asarray(cal_sums).T
means[:, 0] , means[:,1:] = np.unique(a), np.asarray(cal_mean).T

print(sums)
[[ 1. 10.  4.]
 [ 2. 32. 10.]
 [ 3. 26.  8.]
 [ 4.  6. 15.]]

print(means)

[[1.   2.5  1.  ]
 [2.   8.   2.5 ]
 [3.   6.5  2.  ]
 [4.   1.5  3.75]]
```

I tested it in quite large array size and it is fast

```
n = 1000
a = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(n, n))
b = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, n, n))
```

speed:

```
377 ms ± 3.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```